# How does python load all the values in sys.path?

Tags: python, django

I'm a python beginner and I'm in my first days playing with my own python scripts and projects such as django.

I use Ubuntu and I set my PYTHONPATH as

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python2.6:~/Projects/mypython
```

When I run into a python interpreter

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

I can see

> ['', '/usr/bin', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/ropemode-0.1_rc2-py2.6.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/rope-0.9.3-py2.6.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/ropevim-0.3_rc-py2.6.egg', '/usr/lib/python2.6', '/home/jaume/Projects/mypython', '/usr/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PIL', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/gst-0.10', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/IPython/Extensions', u'/home/jaume/.ipython']

How does python load all the non-PYTHONPATH paths? Is there any index? Moreover, I have my django installed at /usr/lib/pymodules and, even it's not in the sys.path list, it runs.

Many thanks.

Comment: To find out how django is loading, check the path: `>>> import django
>>> django.__path__
['/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django']`

Comment: I only can see the ['django']. Maybe it's because its installed from 'apt-get'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a list of every file the Python interpreter on my computer (which is set up similar to, but not the same as, yours) opens before it starts running code provided by me:

```
$ strace -eopen python -c 1 2>&1 | grep -ve '-1 E'
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 3
open("/lib/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY)  = 3
open("/lib/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY)       = 3
open("/lib/libutil.so.1", O_RDONLY)     = 3
open("/usr/lib/libssl.so.0.9.8", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/usr/lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/usr/lib/libz.so.1", O_RDONLY)    = 3
open("/lib/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY)        = 3
open("/lib/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY)        = 3
open("/proc/meminfo", O_RDONLY)         = 3
open("/usr/lib/python2.6/site.py", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/usr/lib/python2.6/site.pyc", O_RDONLY) = 4
open("/usr/lib/python2.6/os.py", O_RDONLY) = 4
open("/usr/lib/python2.6/os.pyc", O_RDONLY) = 5
open("/usr/lib/python2.6/posixpath.py", O_RDONLY) = 5
open("/usr/lib/python2.6/posixpath.pyc", O_RDONLY) = 6
open("/usr/lib/python2.6/stat.py", O_RDONLY) = 6
open("/usr/lib/python2.6/stat.pyc", O_RDONLY) = 7
open("/usr/lib/python2.6/genericpath.py", O_RDONLY) = 6
open("/usr/lib/python2.6/genericpath.pyc", O_RDONLY) = 7
open("/usr/lib/python2.6/warnings.py", O_RDONLY) = 6
open("/usr/lib/python2.6/warnings.pyc", O_RDONLY) = 7
open("/usr/lib/python2.6/linecache.py", O_RDONLY) = 7
open("/usr/lib/python2.6/linecache.pyc", O_RDONLY) = 8
open("/usr/lib/python2.6/types.py", O_RDONLY) = 7
open("/usr/lib/python2.6/types.pyc", O_RDONLY) = 8
open("/usr/lib/python2.6/UserDict.py", O_RDONLY) = 5
open("/usr/lib/python2.6/UserDict.pyc", O_RDONLY) = 6
open("/usr/lib/python2.6/_abcoll.py", O_RDONLY) = 6
open("/usr/lib/python2.6/_abcoll.pyc", O_RDONLY) = 7
open("/usr/lib/python2.6/abc.py", O_RDONLY) = 7
open("/usr/lib/python2.6/abc.pyc", O_RDONLY) = 8
open("/usr/lib/python2.6/copy_reg.py", O_RDONLY) = 5
open("/usr/lib/python2.6/copy_reg.pyc", O_RDONLY) = 6
open("/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
open("/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
open("/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PIL.pth", O_RDONLY) = 4
open("/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pygst.pth", O_RDONLY) = 4
open("/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/python-support.pth", O_RDONLY) = 4
open("/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/wx.pth", O_RDONLY) = 4
open("/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/zope.interface-3.5.3-nspkg.pth", O_RDONLY) = 4
open("/usr/lib/python2.6/sitecustomize.py", O_RDONLY) = 4
open("/usr/lib/python2.6/sitecustomize.pyc", O_RDONLY) = 5
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/usr/lib/python2.6/encodings/__init__.py", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/usr/lib/python2.6/encodings/__init__.pyc", O_RDONLY) = 4
open("/usr/lib/python2.6/codecs.py", O_RDONLY) = 4
open("/usr/lib/python2.6/codecs.pyc", O_RDONLY) = 5
open("/usr/lib/python2.6/encodings/aliases.py", O_RDONLY) = 4
open("/usr/lib/python2.6/encodings/aliases.pyc", O_RDONLY) = 5
open("/usr/lib/python2.6/encodings/utf_8.py", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/usr/lib/python2.6/encodings/utf_8.pyc", O_RDONLY) = 4
```

All of these could, at least potentially, have an effect on sys.path.  It is extremely unlikely that the stuff that comes before `site.py` would, however (those are all OS libraries and interfaces not specific to Python).  I'd suggest you take a hard look at `site.py`, `sitecustomize.py`, and the various `.pth` files (your list of `.pth` files will be different than mine; that's normal).

Answer (score 0):

Read this: http://docs.python.org/library/site.html#module-site