# How can I discover why python sys.path is not standard on my computer?

Tags: python, configuration, path, debian-based

I'm using computers running Debian or Ubuntu.

In the current configuration of my desktop computer (running Xubuntu 14.04), `${HOME}/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` [^1] appears after `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` [^2] in `sys.path`.

It's the contrary in the other computers I use, and the latter is the desired behaviour for me: I want my locally installed packages to prevail over the system-wide installed ones.

How can I figure out where the configuration tweak in my desktop computer comes from?

Do I have to go through every `*.pth` file I find in the system and try to understand what it specifies?

[^1]: where the packages installed via `python setup.py --user` go

[^2]: where the package installed via `apt-get install` seem to go

#### Update:

My question seems related to [How does python load all the values in sys.path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401885/how-does-python-load-all-the-values-in-sys-path)

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4401953/1878788) led me to try this strace trick and I could see that the first opened `.pth` file was `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/easy-install.pth` which contains the following code:

```
import sys; sys.__plen = len(sys.path)
./cutadapt-1.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
./DendroPy-3.12.0-py2.7.egg
./pylint-1.4.0-py2.7.egg
./astroid-1.3.2-py2.7.egg
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
import sys; new=sys.path[sys.__plen:]; del sys.path[sys.__plen:]; p=getattr(sys,'__egginsert',0); sys.path[p:p]=new; sys.__egginsert = p+len(new)
```

Removing the `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` line causes `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` to be retrograded in `sys.path` and appear after `${HOME}/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`.

I'm pretty sure I hadn't manually edited any `.pth` file. So I guess this may be the consequence of some python module I installed as root using `easy-install`. Which one?

From the modification times of the files and directories within `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/`, I can see that `easy-install.pth` has been modified the same day as two directories: `astroid-1.3.2-py2.7.egg` and `pylint-1.4.0-py2.7.egg`.

Next step will be to investigate why these modules' installation into `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` would require an early insertion of `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` into `sys.path`.

Comment: You can modify it yourself

Comment: You mean, modify sys.path ? I know I can do that from within python, but what I want is to be able to fix the global configuration, and also understand why it was broken, so that I may avoid breaking it again either on my desktop computer or on other computers I work with.
Basically, what typically causes the sys.path configuration to be modified? Packages I installed the wrong way? A config file I modified (and forgot about it)?

Comment: No I mean you can modify it globally, create a .sh file in  /etc/profile.d 
 and export  export PATH=$PATH:...